# Got Fatal error CodeIgniter CI_Controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I got following error on every controller

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /<path>/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

The root folder has also its same separate codeigniter system (all ci structure) folder. the site in root in working but when i copy the another ci structure in sub folder i got mentioned fatal error. please help me.

Comment: ` when i copy the another ci structure in sub folder i got mentioned fatal error. ` something is not right.. you you need another CI in subfolder..

Comment: @bipen yes in sub folder another ci structure where i got this error

Comment: have You defined DEFAULT controller in your "routes.php"?

Comment: yes i defined default controller

Comment: so according to Your problem, I think it's the problem in Your .htacces. mention Your correct "project folder name" in .htaccess.

Comment: i solved my problem in database file i check host name before variable but the server is virtual and i check real condition thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your database config in **application/config/database.php** it's one of the major time consuming error message I faced with CI. Because the error message was simply misleading. So, check the DB config first.

Comment: My config file is alright. My  home page working fine but when i click on the any inner page link then the page is blank and on the erro log it show me this error  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /var/www/html/10deals/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Comment: try without clean URL and without .htaccess; do you use any kind of CI plugin? one more thing; in your homepage, is it taking anything from DB? if not then try a query in homepage. You can use back-trace (to see full error stack) to find further detail about that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to run a migration that is within a folder, it appears that my 'git' is with a conflict in the directory separator.

I was trying to run on command line:

```
$ php index.php tools/migration
```

fix it temporarily with the command:

```
$ php index.php tools migration
```